# PHP - Problem with cookies/setcookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm having problems with the following code: http://pastebin.com/MCkhzQjs

This works locally (on localhost) but when I upload it to the server it does not login. I think it is to do with cookies not being sent. The meta refresh is so that the page is refreshed after the cookie is set. Thank for any help.

Comment: Please post real code. Your snippet does not even run due to syntax errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setcookie, Cannot modify header information - headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658083/setcookie-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is simple.

You can only set cookies, start sessions, set headers IF there has been not content echo'd or sent (including html) outside of php code blocks.

Examples:

Won't Work:

```
<div>
<?php setcookie(/*....*/); ?>
</div>
```

Reason: Because the `<div>` has already been sent forcing the headers to be sent, there for cookies cannot be added to the headers, because there sent

Another:

```
<?php
    setcookie(/*....*/); //works
    echo "test";
    setcookie(/*....*/); //does not
?>
```

Your code should look like:

```
$title = "Admin panel";
if(!isset($_COOKIE['login'])) $_COOKIE['login'] = false;
if(!isset($_POST['password'])) $_POST['password'] = false;

if($_POST['password'] == "tt83df")
{
    if(isset($_POST['permlog']))
    {
        $expire = time()+60*60*24*365;
        setcookie("login", "tt83df", $expire, "/admin");
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie("login", "tt83df", 0, "/admin");
    }
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;//Stop here and SEND Headers
}
if($_COOKIE['login'] == "tt83df")
{
    $html = '<ul><li><a href="news_panel.php">News control panel</a></li><li><a href="video_panel.php">Video control panel</a></li><li><a href="schedule_panel.php">Schedule control panel</a></li>
    <li><a href="events_panel.php">Events control panel</a></li><li><a href="notices_panel.php">Notices control panel</a></li></ul>';
}else
{
    $html = 'Password:<form method="post"><input type="password" name="password" /><input type="submit" value="Submit"><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="permlog" value="true" /> Stay logged in? (do not use on a public computer)</form>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="images/favicon.ico" /> 
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $html; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you error_reporting enabled? Your code contains whitespaces before the first php-tag, what is an output and forces the server to send the headers(error_reporting should give you a notice about that).

Comment: I have error reporting locally (and there are no errors) but not on the server. There is code before this code, so there is white space before.

Comment: @John: He's talking about text outside of the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: I don't have the cookie set locally (eg. used different browsers, incognito). Whitespace outside of the php tags shouldn't change anything?

Comment: Whitespace outside of the php tags would change anything!

Comment: Just enable your error_reporting, and you will see what happens.

Comment: It's a shared server, so I can't change the settings

Comment: error_reporting() is a php-function and doesn't require changes on server-settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue consist of setting a cookie after writing HTML to the output stream. Cookies or header modifications can only done before the header is sent. Writing content to the output stream forces the header to be automatically written.

Try using `ob_start();` at the top of your code, and `ob_end_flush();` at the bottom. This will initialize a buffer which will be filled with everything that is written to your output stream. So basically. `ob_start` is for initializing an output buffer, and `ob_end_flush` for writing the buffer back to the client.