# How to set a cookie for signup page?

Tags: php

I am new to php programming. I designed a signup form for my site. After signup anyone can download some files in that site. Now  I am looking for to set cookie for signup page.

```
<div class="field submit" style="text-align:center;">
  <input type="submit" value="signup"/>
  <?php 
    setcookie("signup",time()+3600, "/");
    if (isset($_COOKIE['signup'])) { 
      print "<p>Hello $_COOKIE[signup]</p>";         
    } else { 
      print "<p>Hello, This is your first visit</p>"; 
    } 
  ?> 
</div>
```

I am using the code like this but it was showing a warning.

Comment: What warning is it showing?

Comment: Can you post the warning you getting ?

Comment: `$_COOKIE[signup]` still needs string encapsulation. `$_COOKIE['signup']`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php .. value (second) parameter missing

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:  print "<p>Hello $_COOKIE['signup']</p>";  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/clovefnm/public_html/Example/signup1/samplecook.php on line

Answer (score 1):

You passing wrong parameter to [setcookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), you missing second parameter `value` in it.

```
setcookie("signup","username",time()+3600, "/");
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G5VlJE)**.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clovefnm/public_html/Example/signup1/samplecook.php:16) in /home/clovefnm/public_html/Example/signup1/samplecook.php on line 33

Comment: I passed the second parameter also, again it was showing the same warning

Comment: <input type="submit" value="signup"/>
                        <?php 
                            setcookie("signup" ,"name",$_POST["signup"]);
                         if (isset($_COOKIE['signup']))
                         { 
                             print "<p>Hello $_COOKIE[signup]</p>";         
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 
                             print "<p>Hello, This is your first visit</p>"; 
                         } 
                        ?>

Comment: Do you have header redirect script in your code ? I cannot see in the code you psoted in question. Can you post the compete code as if line:33 ?

Comment: Rikesh  I put my code in pastebin see this link http://pastebin.com/Sa0iZBTt                                 Thank you

Comment: You haven't posted `samplecook.php` where actually you getting this warning.

Comment: Rikesh i renamed the samplecook.php to signupform.php

Comment: I got error like this Notice: Undefined index: signup in D:\localserver\htdocs\signup\signupform.php on line 32
Hello, This is your first visit

Comment: before setcookie line check if $_POST really contains signup var in it. Something like `if(isset($_POST['signup']))`.

Comment: Hi Rikesh i didnt get the solution of cookie

Comment: What problem you facing ?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/clovefnm/public_html/Example/signup8th/signupdbapr8th.php:23) in /home/clovefnm/public_html/Example/signup8th/signupdbapr8th.php on line 54

Comment: i renamed the signupdbapr8th.php to signupdb.php

Comment: @Sujitha - you should have setcookie function call before any html output in your file. refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658083/setcookie-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent).

Comment: No rikesh , still im in confusion

Comment: Rikesh i sent mail to u pls check it once

Comment: i sent to hotmail rikesh , that only u put it in profile right

Comment: oh god ,then wat should i do ? rikesh

Comment: i sent mail from my gmail .. rikesh