# why log file not work after the loop?

Tags: php, cookies

I write some log file on my server after the submit data from other server automatically when my payment is success. my cookies log file are working well but after the loop it not working.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $roomname          = $_POST['roomname'];
        $cartinfo          = $_POST['cartinfo'];    

        $str = substr_replace($cartinfo, $roomname, 2, 0);
        $arrs = explode(",", $str);
        $numArrs = array_shift($arrs);
        array_walk($arrs, function(&$val, $key) {  $val = explode(';',$val); });

        //work at this step 

        // $payload ="hello";
        // $steal = fopen("1.txt", "a");
        // fwrite($steal, $payload ."\n"); 
        // fclose($steal);

        $ans = array();

        for($i=0; $i<$numArrs; $i++) {
            $ans[] = array_column($arrs, $i);
        }

        //Not working.... 
        $payload ="hello";
        $steal = fopen("1.txt", "a");
        fwrite($steal, $payload ."\n"); 
        fclose($steal);

        foreach ($ans as $key => $value) {
            $roomname = $value[0];
            $roomqty  = $value[1];
            $arrival  = $value[2];
            $departure= $value[3];
            //insert data into database
        }           
    }

?>
```

The post method will be submit by other server automatically. I goal is to insert data in the loop if the payment is succes..

Comment: I don't see anything about cookies in that code.

Comment: @Barmar I edit bro

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Are there any error messages?

Comment: I don't think you're using the term 'cookies' correctly...

Comment: @Devon Sorry bro it not cookies. it is data log from request post data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your cookies aren't working well after the loop because you are `echo`ing some content in it:

```
echo $roomname = $value[0];
echo $roomqty  = $value[1];
echo $arrival  = $value[2];
echo $departure= $value[3];
```

The `echo`s will send data to the client so that you are not able to call `header()`, `setcookie()` etc.

Please have a look at:
[setcookie, Cannot modify header information - headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658083/setcookie-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Is the code not reached or are there any errors?