# How to resolve uncaught type error: unsupported operand types.... in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, cookies, typeerror, setcookie

I created a form which works using cookies in PHP. This is how the form looks like.
[image: the form]

When I put values for price and quantity, I want them to get multiplied and the result to be displayed in the "Total Bill Value" textbox. Each time I put values for price and quantity, I want them to get added up, which is why I have used a cookie. This is my code.

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            $result=0;
           
            if(isset($_POST["btnReset"]))
            {
                setcookie("result", $result); 
            }

            elseif(isset($_POST["btnClick"]))
            {
                if(isset($_COOKIE["result"]))
                {
                    $result=$_COOKIE["result"];
                }
                $result= $result + $_POST["Price"]*$_POST["Quantity"];
                setcookie("result", $result);
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($_COOKIE["result"]))
                {
                    echo "something";
                }
                
    
            }
        }
    ?>

<?php 
if (isset($result)) {
    $bill = $result;
} else {
    $bill = '';
}
?>
    
        <form method="POST" >
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li>
                    Product Name: <input type="text" name="ProductName"> <br>
                    Price: <input type="number" name="Price" value="price"> <br>
                    Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity" value="qty"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnClick" value="Add"> 
                    <input type="submit" name="btnReset" value="Clear">
                    <input type="submit" name="btnPrint" value="Print"><br>
                    Total Bill Value: <input type="text" name="Bill" value="<?php echo $bill; ?>">                 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>


         
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

But whenever I click the "Add" button, I'm getting this error
[image: The error]

Line 21 is this

```
 $result= $result + $_POST["Price"]*$_POST["Quantity"];
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting that error??

And the other thing is, when I enter product name, price and quantity and get the total bill value and do that for many products and hit on the "Print" button, I want all the products with their total bill values to get printed out. How do I do this?

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Edit: So I did a var_dump to $result
[image: code]

and this is what I got

[image: var_dump($result)]

Comment: In the line above 21, do a `var_dump($result);` to check what it actually contains at that point. The error suggests it's an array (which you can't use in a calculation like that)

Comment: yes it is giving me an array, but I don't understand why? I haven't defined $result as an array :/

Comment: What does the array contain? Can you please update your question with the output? Are you setting the same cookie elsewhere as well?

Comment: Okay, I updated it. No :/ The code I've included in my question is the full code. Actually it was working fine, and I was experimenting with putting the cookie in an array and stuff, but then I removed all those codes, and now when I run the original code I had (which is this) it is not working. (I hope what I'm saying is clear :E )

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is move your PHP code above the opening `<html>` tag, this will help avoid warnings with `setcookie` ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658083/setcookie-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)).

I've rewritten your code slightly, renaming the buttons and values. It's been tested in PHP version 5.4.45.

```php
<?php

// Default result value
$result = 0;

if ( !empty( $_POST ) ) {

    $cookie_key = 'result';
    $action = !empty( $_POST[ 'action' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'action' ] : false;
    $result = !empty( $_COOKIE[ $cookie_key ] ) ? (float)$_COOKIE[ $cookie_key ] : $result;


    // Add product
    if ( $action === 'add' ) {
        $price = !empty( $_POST[ 'Price' ] ) ? (float)$_POST[ 'Price' ] : 0;
        $quantity = !empty( $_POST[ 'Quantity' ] ) ? (int)$_POST[ 'Quantity' ] : 0;
        if ( $price && $quantity ) {
            $result = $result + ( $price * $quantity );
        }
    }

    // Clear result
    else if ( $action === 'clear' ) {
        $result = 0;
    }

    // Print
    else if ( $action === 'print' ) {
        // Handle print action
    }

    // Store value
    setcookie( $cookie_key, $result );
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" >
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
                Product Name: <input type="text" name="ProductName"> <br>
                Price: <input type="number" name="Price" value="price"> <br>
                Quantity: <input type="number" name="Quantity" value="qty"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="add"> 
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="clear">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="print"><br>
                Total Bill Value: <input type="text" name="Bill" value="<?php echo $result; ?>">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I copied the code and tried it out, but the calculations aren't coming correctly? for example if I put 4*5, I'm getting 21. Also, the results are supposed to get added up, which is why I have used a cookie. That is if I enter 2*3 in my first try, and then I put 5*6 in my second, then the total bill value should be 6+30 = 36.

Comment: @adria not sure why you're getting issues. I've added a screenrecording of the above code running in my local enviroment using the examples you provided and it works as expected.